# Get the value of a span and add the value to and input field

Tags: jquery

I have a range slider and I would like to get the data-slider attribute to be added to the input field as it number increases or get the span value add to the input field:

```
<div class="small-10 medium-11 columns">
   <div class="range-slider" data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput3;" data-slider="35">
      <span class="range-slider-handle" tabindex="0" role="slider" style="transform: translateX(287.75px);"></span>
      <span class="range-slider-active-segment" style="width: 35%;"></span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="small-2 medium-1 columns">
   <span id="sliderOutput3">35</span>
</div>
<input id="donationamount" type="text" value="50" name="donationamount">
```

I tried this but it doesn't set the value:

```
$('#sliderOutput3').on('change', function() {
   var tc =  $('#sliderOutput3').text();
   $('#donationamount').val(tc);
});
```

Comment: The change event is not known by the `span`. Doesn't you slider has its own events on change?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="small-10 medium-11 columns">
    <div class="range-slider" data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput3;" data-slider="35">
        <span class="range-slider-handle" tabindex="0" role="slider" style="transform: translateX(287.75px);"></span>
        <span class="range-slider-active-segment" style="width: 35%;"></span>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="small-2 medium-1 columns">
    <span id="sliderOutput3">35</span>
</div>
<input id="donationamount" type="text" value="50" name="donationamount">
<br>
<input id="donationamount2" type="text" value="50" name="donationamount2">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#sliderOutput3').ready(function() {
    //example 1
        var tc =  $('#sliderOutput3').text();
        $('#donationamount').val(tc);

   //example 2
        var dataSlider = $(".range-slider").attr("data-slider");
        $('#donationamount2').val(dataSlider);
});
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/8bbrwmh0/2/)

it can be?

Comment: This doesn't quite work.. It sets the input to the slides default value.. so if you refresh the page it will be on 35 if you move the slide the amount does not change as the numbers increase.. can anyone help